# How do I pass a $params array as parameters to a function?

Tags: php, arrays, parameters

How can I convert an array of various-typed parameters to actual parameters in a function?

```
$params = array( 'the title2', 'the footer2', 10);
displayTest(implode(',', $params)); //how???
displayTest(convert_to_parameters($params)); //how???

function displayTest($title, $footer, $numberOfItems = 0) {
    $r = '';
    $r .= '<div>'.$title.'</div>';
    for($index = 0; $index < $numberOfItems; $index++) {
        $r .= '<div>the text</div>';
    }
    $r .= '<div>'.$footer.'</div>';
    return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [call_user_func_array()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to do this:

```
 call_user_func_array('displayTest', $params);
```